# Amazon amazon product advertising api temporary credentials

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-product-api

I would like to sign a request with temporary credentials for a AWSECommerceService request to Amazon. The reason for this that I don't want to add the secret key to the the mobile clients directly.

I'm running a server that returns a Cognito openId session token to the client. This token is then traded for temp credentials. With those credentials I'm trying to sign the http request.

To accomplish this I add the X-Amz-Security-Token parameter to the request like described here [Amazon Docu](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#UsingTemporarySecurityCredentials).

The issue is that the result is always a "Bad Request 400 InvalidAccount Invalid AccessKey Id ASIAxxx". I also tried to generate the signature before adding the token but the result was the same. Any ideas are appreciated.

Request:

> http://webservices.amazon.de/onca/xml?AWSAccessKeyId=ASIAxxx&AssociateTag=mytag&BrowseNode=1981808031&Operation=ItemSearch&ResponseGroup=Images%2CItemAttributes%2COffers&SearchIndex=All&Service=AWSECommerceService&Sort=price&Timestamp=2017-07-12T15%3A16%3A48Z&X-Amz-Security-Token=mySessionToken&Signature=mySignature

Client: (Junit test to tesing signing)

```
    BasicSessionCredentials credentials = CognitoWebClient.authenticateWithToken(jsonResult);
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

        params.put("Service", "AWSECommerceService");
                params.put("Operation", "ItemSearch");
                params.put("AWSAccessKeyId", credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId()));
                    params.put("AssociateTag", myTag);
                    params.put("SearchIndex", "All");
                    params.put("ResponseGroup", 
                    params.put("Images,ItemAttributes,Offers");
                    params.put("Sort", "price");
                    params.put("BrowseNode", myNode);
                    params.put("X-Amz-Security-Token", mySessionToken);

       String requestUrl = SignedRequestsHelper.getInstance(amazonLocale.getEndpoint(), credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId(), credentials.getAWSSecretKey()).sign(params);

            RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();

        try{
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = template.getForEntity(requestUrl, String.class);
            Assert.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK,responseEntity.getStatusCode());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail(requestUrl+"\n"+e.getMessage());

        }
```

[SignedRequestsHelper](https://github.com/agentgt/JavaAmazonProductAdvertisingClient/blob/master/src/com/evocatus/amazonclient/SignedRequestsHelper.java)

Server: (Returns the openId token to the client)

```
public String getIdentityIdToken() {

        // initialize the Cognito identity client with a set
        // of anonymous AWS credentials
        AmazonCognitoIdentityClientBuilder identityClientBuilder = AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.builder()
                .withCredentials(new AWSCredentialsProvider() {

                    @Override
                    public void refresh() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public AWSCredentials getCredentials() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return new BasicAWSCredentials(myRealAccessKey,
                                myRealSecretAccessKey);
                    }
                });

        identityClientBuilder.setRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1.getName());

        AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient = identityClientBuilder.build();

        // send a get id request. This only needs to be executed the first time
        // and the result should be cached.
        GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest tokenRequest = new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest();
        tokenRequest.setIdentityPoolId(myIdentityPool);

        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("login.com....", "myUser");
        tokenRequest.setLogins(map);

        GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult result = identityClient
                .getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(tokenRequest);

        return result.getToken();
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you're trying to do? And how you're using Cognito? I don't recognize that client, despite it being Java.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I added more details. Thank you for your comment